# How to add another option to website and

Tags: javascript, php, html, database, web

I have a javascript that shows and hides options from a html form. What I am trying to do is be able for the user to add a new category and then write that into the database as an option and add that subject to the option form.

Here is an example of the html code,

```
<select id="team1" name="team1" style="display:none">
<option value="subcat1">subcat1</option>
<option value="subcat2">subcat2</option>
<option value="subcat3">subcat3</option>
```

I then want them to be able to add another `subcat4` via the website.

the javascript i'm using is an if statement with show and hides from different selects.

The user needs to be able to enter the category name and add it to the relevant select.

Currently im unsure on how to get this to add and save the new `subcat4` to the database and to the html.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you first load the page you construct the select element by using the values stored in the database.

Then you can have a form that posts the filled info and stores subcategories into the database. This form may contain the identifier of your select for knowing in which select you are assigning the new option. It could be in a hidden input.

here comes a simple example of that form

```
<form method='post' action='/your/action/here' >
    <input type='hidden' name='main_category' value='team1' /> 
    Subcategory: <input type='text' name='subcategory' value='' />
    <input type='submit' name='submit_btn' value='submit' />
</form>
```

You could also do it without page refresh by using an ajax post (this should be your next step, make it first work the simple way) to store the info and then by appending the option to your select using javascript. Check the jquery [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) or the appendChild() if you are not using jquery.

Comment: okay thanks, i will try that i'm trying to avoid jquery as i prefer doing just js

Comment: im using a append child() document.getElementById("category").appendChild(newListItem); but was wandering as i have 3 select's i want them to be able to choose so the department their in then the category for their department would i need to use a var with appendchild? still learning how to code :)

Comment: Each select must have a different id attribute. You use this id here to specify in which element to append document.getElementById("the desired id goes here")

Comment: aye i understand that, would i be able to do a multiple get elementbyid or have to do 3 different forms for each category? thanks for your help :)

Comment: you can add a select with 3 options in your form. Those options will be your 3 different main categories.

Comment: okay as i currently have 3 selects with multiple options which are different for each select, what i want to know is by using the appendchild() would i need an append for each select or is there a way of having the user choose which of the 3 selects to add to?

Comment: This is what I explained to you above. With your form you append an option(subcategory) to your select(one of the main categories). Now, by adding a select in your form, you give the power to user to select, to which of the main categories to add the extra option. How can you identify the main categories? You can by their different ids.

Comment: ah okay i understand what you mean now thanks:) will let you know how i get on!:)

Comment: have got it work, thanks for your help! sorry took my time getting my head around it!

Answer (score 0):

With jquery you can do this code to append new child in your select element.

```
$('#team1').append('<option value="subcat4">subcat4</option>');
```